# How can I pass attribute to an imported hidden custom polymer element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

Before I created my custom Polymer element :

```
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element" attributes="key" hidden>
  <script>
    Polymer({});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I would like to pass an attribute to my imported hidden custom Polymer element when I import it on an other custom Polymer element like this :

```
<link rel="import" href="../my-custom-element/my-custom-element.html" key="15">
```

How could I do ? It is possible to do this ? If not what is the good way ?

Comment: as the answer you rejected says that isn't how polymer works. you have to use the element before you can set a attribute to it. just importing the element isn't the same as using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wirlez pointed out, you'll want to import your element's definition, create an instance, and set the key value as an attribute.

For example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Polymer</title>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <!-- import element definition from jsbin -->
    <link rel="import" href="http://jsbin.com/mojadu.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo key="42"></x-foo>
  </body>
</html>
```

**element definition**

```
<!-- Make sure your element imports Polymer as a dependency -->
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="x-foo" attributes="key" hidden>
  <template>
    <h1>Hello from x-foo</h1>
    <h2>The key is {{key}}</h2>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      keyChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
        console.log('the key is', newVal);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

[Here's the example running in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mutuma/1/edit?html,output).

If you look in the console, you'll see the element is logging the value for key.

If you're trying to access the element using JavaScript in `index.html` you may need to wait for [the `polymer-ready` event](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready) before manipulating it.

ex:

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
  var el = document.querySelector('x-foo');
  // do something with x-foo that involves its key
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a custom attribute you need a custom element. The tag "link" is no custom element. To create your own custom-elements and implement them to your web-application [read this](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html).

If you haven't already, follow the whole tutorial :)

**Edit:**
An import of a custom element is not the same as using it. What you can do it that you import your custom element then write the tag with specific attributes.

```
<my-custom-element key="15"></my-custom-element>
```

Much like core-ajax is used:

```
<core-ajax
    auto
    url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
    params='{"alt":"json", "q":"chrome"}'
    handleAs="json"
    on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}"></core-ajax>
```

It seems like you want to have it like this:

```
<link
    rel="import"
    href="../core-ajax/my-custom-element.html"
    auto
    url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
    params='{"alt":"json", "q":"chrome"}'
    handleAs="json"
    on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}"></link>
```

Sorry that is not how Polymer works!

Comment: Thanks, I already follow the tutorial. You answer not responding to my need.

Answer (score 0):

lets say this is you polymer file:

```
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element" attributes="key" hidden>
      <script>
        Polymer({});
      </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

and this is your link importing the file in your html:

```
<link rel="import" href="../my-custom-element/my-custom-element.html" key="15">
```

there's a couple of ways to do what you ask...

if you wish to create that value dynamically then the best way is to create a constructor for the custom element like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-custom-element" constructor='MyCustomElement' attributes="key" hidden>
          <script>
            Polymer({});
          </script>
        </polymer-element>
```

then create an instance of such element on the code of the polymer element, something like:

```
var custom =  new MyCustomElement();
```

place that element into your DOM like:

```
var dom = document.querySelector('otherElement'); //depending on scope
dom.appendChild(custom);
custom.setAttribute('atribute', value);

or
this.$.elementID.appendChild(custom);
custom.setAttribute('atribute', value);
```

I hope this is somewhat what you're looking for. cheers